# UIWebView - main loop mode kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I'm loading a UIWebView by using the method `loadData`. With some specific data which is quite long, I'm getting the following error:

```
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:) 
failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

It occurs after `webViewDidFinishLoad`. Any idea how can I find out what I'm doing wrong? I'm not using any javascript.

Comment: It sounds like you're giving it too much data, and the callback is timeing out.  Try cutting your data in half and loading the view.  Keep cutting in half and loading until it fits, then you'll know how much the web view can handle.

Comment: Does this occur while you are debugging, after stopping at some breakpoint inside of `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:`?

Comment: I cut the data and UIWebView loaded the data successfully, as @Rayfleck suggests. How is this problem normally solved? I can see there isn't any setTimeout to the UIWebView.

Comment: I haven't implemented the method webView:didFinishLoadForFrame because I'm working on an iPhone app. According to the doc, the method is available on the delegate WebFrameLoadDelegate, which is not available for iPhone dev. In the doc, it isn't mentioned any limit to the data that can be loaded in the UIWebView... I guess I'll have to find out the data limit and load the UIWebView in chunks.

Comment: i have stuck with same, But i am loading UIWebView with one HTML file which contains Javascript.. Please let me know if you have any idea....

Answer (score 1):

the issue is that a web view does not want to get 'stuck' calling a delegate that may or may not return

so it throws that error after 30s saying that it is the DELEGATES fault that things dont continue

what you can do is :

```
- (void)webview:(id)wv didFinishLoadForFrame:(id)f {
    [self performSelector:@selector(delayedDidFinish:) withObject:f afterDelay:0.0];
}

- (void)delayedDidFinish:(id)f {
    ...
}
```

That will let the delegate return and then run stuff when the runloop comes around the next time

====

with GCD, just use `dispatch_async` - more modern than `performSelector:`